# Difference between $elemMatch and $in

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

I am building a chat app using mongoose and nestjs. This is my first attempt of using mongo as database so I am having trouble differentiate which mongo query should I be using.

The following function is to find one on one chat between logged in user and other user. I tested the two approach in Insomnia and they come back the same result.

Approach 1

```
async findOneOnOneChat(currentUserId, userId) {
  const oneOnOneChat = await this.chatModel
    .find({
      isGroupChat: false,
    })
    .and([
      { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: currentUserId } } },
      { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } }
    ])
  return oneOnOneChat;
}
```

Approach 2

```
async findOneOnOneChat(currentUserId, userId) {
  const oneOnOneChat = await this.chatModel
    .find({
      isGroupChat: false,
    })
    .and([{ users: { $in: userId } }, { users: { $in: id } }])
  return oneOnOneChat;
}
```

So my question is what is the difference between two approach? Which approach is better? Or is there a better version can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different things.

Use `{ users: { $in: userId } }` when `userId` is an array, and you want the `user` value(s) to match one or more of the elements in `userId`. In this case `user` can be a single value or array of values, but `userId` must be an array. You can think of it as a loop on `userId`, that for each element in `userId` is searching for a match in `user`.

Use `{ users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } }` where `users` is an array and `userId` is a single value. You can think of it as a loop on `users`, that for each element in `users` is searching for a match that equals `userId`.